# Converting My code to work with ie11 and receiving an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

How do I use `...` within IE with the code below? I'm new to using `...` and it's hard for me to convert it so that it works with IE11.

I'm using angularJS here, but the code below isn't working on IE and it's throwing a syntax error at `...new`. Sadly, I can't use babel in this instance.

```js
scope.model.locations = res.sort(function(a, b) {
  (a.locationName > b.locationName) ? 1: -1
});
scope.model.jobCategories = [...new Set(scope.model.jobCategories)];
```

Comment: Try -> `Array.from(new Set(scope.model.jobCategories))`

Comment: `Array.from` [isn't supported in IE11](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Array_static_methods)

Comment: All the line does is de-duplicate jobCategories, so you could look at alternatives for de-duplicating an array->  eg.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array

Comment: [IE11 doesn't support constructor arguments to `Set` either](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Set_constructor_arguments).